# C#: Pass by reference in a constructor or pass as a parameter in through an update loop?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I have an object that I need updated data from in every update in a game loop (in C#). Is it better to pass-by-reference the object into the constructor of the object that performs the update loop so that the reference constantly has the up-to-date object,

or should I pass it normally as a parameter into the Update method (which is called every update)?

So this as a constructor:

```
public UpdatingObject(ref DataObject dataObject)
```

or this as an update loop header (passed-by-value as default):

```
public void Update(DataObject dataObject)
```

Comment: If the object is an instance of a reference type (that is, a class rather than a struct) then you should not use the ref keyword.

Comment: @phoog: I could imagine a scenario in which a `ref` argument may be set, but perhaps not.  In this case you would have to use `ref` as `out` wouldn't work.  You're right though, it would be a rare scenario.

Comment: @Ed S. what I meant to say is that the description of the problem sounds to me like neither the ref nor out keyword is needed here, unless the object in question is a value type.  It's hard to say for certain, though, without a more complete code sample.

Comment: @phoog: Ah, in that case I completely agree, and asked the OP why he was doing this in my response.

Comment: I actually just read about reference types vs value types in C# and you guys are right; I don't actually need to pass by reference since the the value passed for the DataObject class is a reference type. Thank you for the prompt responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass by reference when you need to, i.e., when you need to reassign the reference to refer to a different object:

```
void ByRef(ref object o)
{
    o = new object();
}
```

If the method guarantees to set `o` then pass it as an `out` parameter.

The default semantics (pass by copy of reference) are suitable for most needs as you typically only modify fields/properties on an object.

If the argument is a value type then you would need to use `ref` to mutate the argument in a way that the caller would see.

My question is; why are you mutating an argument to a constructor?  It seem a bit odd to me.

Comment: What do you mean by mutating an argument to a constructor? I want to pass the argument into the constructor to make it class variable that can be accessed by the Update method. Any mutation of the argument would be done in other classes. This class only needs to be able to get data from the argument.

Comment: @BlakeThiessen: Then you don't need to use `ref` at all; simply take a copy of the reference and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Pass by reference when you have to.

However, would you be able to do define update method in your DataObject class and define another composite class to perform update ? something like that.

```
public class DataObject 
{
   public void Update()
   { 
     // define your update method.
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh, the DataObject is already updated in a separate composite class. I just thought that I had to specifically pass the DataObject into UpdatingObject (which I poorly named UpdatingObject because it contained the Update method mentioned directly afterwards) by reference because I thought the DataObject might only be a "snapshot" instance of the DataObject and would not contain changes following the passing of the object. But since I understood class references to be passed by value, I understand I don't need to constantly pass an updated version of the DataObject into the UpdatingObject.